# Mockito creates different instances?

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, mockito

I have an enterprise Java bean with some `javax.inject.Inject` injected dependencies. I also have a test class which mocks these dependencies with `@Mock` and `@Produces` annotations. Everything works fine except that Mockito seems to create different instances for the bean (`MyDependency@50778`) and for the test class (`MyDependency@50835`), therefore `verify()` calls always fail since all the calls happen on the bean instance and the check is done on the test instance. The most interesting part is that on the continuous integration server the tests run fine, the problem seems to be with my local environment. I see no significant difference between the CI server logs and the output of the local run.

I'm aware that I can't include all of my local preferences, project settings, logs, whatsoever here, so it's hopeless that somebody could blindly point out what the actual problem is here. What I'm looking for is a general guideline... a hint that I could follow to hunt down the problem: what can possibly make Mockito to create different instances for my injected dependency?

**EDIT** (code added for clarity, since it was asked for. I'm not sure if it changes anything about the question):

```
public class MyClass {

    @Inject
    private MyDependencyInterface myDependency; 

    public void callDependency() {
        myDependency.called();
    }
}

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyTestClass {

    @Inject
    private MyClass myObject;

    @Inject
    private MyOtherClass myOtherObject;

    @Produces
    @Mock
    private static MyDependencyInterface dependency;

    @Before
    public void mockDependency() {
        dependency = Mockito.mock(MyDependencyInterface.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testCallDependency() {
        myObject.callDependency();
        Mockito.verify(dependency, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testOtherStuff() {
        myOtherObject.call();
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: no code, no answer :). It's probably a misconfiguration, so it's difficult to *blindly point out what the actual problem is here* :).

Comment: What kind of injection are you using?

Comment: @Augusto I'm sure that it's a misconfiguration. I just have no idea what can even be misconfigured here that can cause something like this.

Comment: @Tomas concrete class used for the injection added to the question

Comment: I know this is not really relevant to the question, and I don't know if you can/want to do this, but since CDI is creating multiple instances of the mock, have you tried `@Produces @ApplicationScoped`?

Comment: @francescoforesti I just tried. it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing using the `@Mock` annotation, but then in your `@Before` method you are creating another mock and re-assigning it to that field. I'm not familiar with `Arquillian.class`, but if that is initializing your mocks for you, then you are creating a second mock in your `@Before` method, which will be a different object from the one that is injected.

Comment: This is somewhat true. (Except that if I remove the creating in the `@Before` method then suddenly I get a `NullPointerException` because `@Mock` doesn't really initialize the mocks for some reason.) The thing I really don't get is that how can this work on the CI server. Because even if there is a misconfiguration either there or on my machine, re-assigning a reference that is already loaded by CDI should screw things up like this.

Comment: I understand. I'm not familiar with some of the libraries you are using, but I know Mockito well, so I can try answering from that perspective. Do you think there may be any difference in your dependencies between your machine and your CI server? Are you using any snapshot dependencies? I'm wondering if there's a version difference causing different behavior.

Comment: Hm... apparently the CI server uses a local maven repository to speed things up skipping network access. Things should not differ there, but just to make sure I need to investigate this further.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, as I still haven't figured out what's going on, and how could this work with the old code and CDI, but here is the workaround that I used to solve this:

```
@Before
public void mockDependency() {
    dependency = Mockito.mock(MyDependencyInterface.class);
}
```

became

```
@Before
public void mockDependency() {
    if (dependency == null) {
        dependency = Mockito.mock(MyDependencyInterface.class);
    } else {
        Mockito.reset(dependency);
    }
    // everything else continues as before
}
```

This was the dependency is initialized at least once, but after CDI got the reference it only gets reset. The reference remains the same, `verify()` calls are called on the same instance as the method calls were called on. Everybody's happy, [except me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDp1l.jpg).